# How to get the array length of an expression parameter

Tags: c#, .net, expression-trees

This method should return a function which can evaluate the scalar product of two vectors of the same size:

```
public static Func<T[], T[], T> GetVectorMultiplyFunction<T>() where T : struct
{
    var x = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T[]), "x");
    var y = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T[]), "y");


    var body = Enumerable
        .Range(0, 3 /*Expression.ArrayLength(x)*/)
        .Select(i => Expression.Multiply(
            Expression.ArrayIndex(x, Expression.Constant(i)),
            Expression.ArrayIndex(y, Expression.Constant(i))
        ))
        .Aggregate(Expression.Add);

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T[], T[], T>>(body, x, y);

    return lambda.Compile();
}
```

But in order to do that, I need to know the length of an array. There's a method `Expression.ArrayLength()` which returns `UnaryExpression` instead of the `int` and the expression cannot be cast explicitly to int. Is there a way of evaluating the array length as `int` beforehand?

**UPD**

Here's a unit test showing how this method should work:

```
[Test]
public void GetVectorMultiplyFunctionReturnsFunctionForInt()
{
    var first = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
    var second = new int[] { 2, 2, 2 };
    var expected = 1 * 2 + 2 * 2 + 3 * 2;
    var func = GetVectorMultiplyFunction<int>();
    var actual = func(first, second);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

Comment: @sruartd `NodeType` returns just the Type of the expression (for ArrayLength it's System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionType.ArrayLength), but i need to have an integer that I can pass to `Enumerable.Range()`

Comment: Why do you need to use the LINQ Expression Builder API? Your input and output types are delegates.

Comment: @AluanHaddad please tell me if there is another way of doing it, I though the only way to deal with multiple parameter types in the same method is by using Linq.Expressions.

Comment: Not sure if I follow you. Is this about trying to implement a generic math library?

Comment: You could always use `dynamic`. The caching is surprisingly performant. Supposedly the next version of the language will allow this to be expressed statically

Comment: @AluanHaddad It's an assingment. I can't use `dynamic` because of the task requirements (method should have this signature `public static Func<T[], T[], T> GetVectorMultiplyFunction<T>() where T : struct`). If I would want to use dynamics I would have to change the method signature, which I can't unfortunately.

Comment: The problem is that you're executing `Enumerable.Range` in your expression builder, but it actually needs to execute inside your compiled expression, when the array length is known. You will need to use `Expression.Call` to execute `Enumerable.Range`.

Comment: @kastrbl4nik you really should have said you were doing some homework assignment. How are people going to help you if they don't know that you're restricted to arbitrary techniques. I don't know what kind of assignment it is, but C# hasn't been able to abstract over operators until C# 11 and the very latest version of the framework, dotnet 7. Either the assignment is intended to illustrate how to overcome language limitations or they've stuck you with an advanced scenario. That would be fine, excellent in fact, but they should be teaching the trade-offs of techniques, including dynamic.

Comment: Anyway, you can write this code entirely statically and without using the LINQ Expression Builder API if you use dynamic types, pattern matching, runtime reflection which would be shit code in this case, or using beautiful but complex language features that solve specific problems like abstracting over static members members in generic constraints. I do suspect that you have the intent wrong. Make sure you clarify with your instructor.

Comment: Lastly, please note that someone assigning you a task like this wouldn't use something as blasphemous as parallel arrays to represent ad hoc pairs of vectors to compute Dot products. Using this function introduces so Using this function introduces numerous chances for bugs and obscures the code. Simply picking the shortest length is mathematically insane, and it makes the API ridiculously opaque

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only parts of your code that require expression trees (assuming you can't use generic math or dynamics as per the other two solutions) are the operators (add and multiply).

If you compile the operator expressions separately, you can then use LINQ very easily, as per your original approach - something like this:

```cs
public static Func<T[], T[], T> GetVectorMultiplyFunction<T>() where T : struct
{
    static Func<T,T,T> GetOperatorFunction(Func<Expression, Expression, BinaryExpression> operatorExpression)
    {
        var x = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var y = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var body = operatorExpression(x, y);

        return Expression
            .Lambda<Func<T, T, T>>(body, x, y)
            .Compile();
    }

    var add = GetOperatorFunction(Expression.Add);
    var multiply = GetOperatorFunction(Expression.Multiply);

    return (xVector, yVector) =>
        xVector
            .Zip(yVector, multiply)
            .Aggregate(add);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The length of an array is not part of the type definition, it's a value you can only obtain at runtime.

With the recent introduction of [Generic Math](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/math), you can multiply and add values using generics without needing to build an expression tree;

```cs
public static T Calc<T>(T[] x, T[] y)
    where T : struct, IMultiplyOperators<T,T,T>, IAdditionOperators<T,T,T>
{
     T result = default(T);

     for(var i = 0; i < x.Length && i < y.Length; i++)
         result += x[i] * y[i];

     return result;
}
```

But I assume that for your assignment you are expected to build an expression tree equivalent to the above method, then compile it.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be what you want but seems to solve your problem if all you need to retain is the signature:

```
public static Func<T[], T[], T> GetVectorMultiplyFunction<T>() where T : struct
{
     return (T[] x, T[] y) => {
     T result = default(T);      

     for(var i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
     {
         var xd = (dynamic)x[i];
         var yd = (dynamic)y[i];
         result += (xd * yd);
     }
     
     return result;
};
```